# applying onkeyup function simultaneously on multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose I have a column of 1+7 text box. Name of the first box is mm1 and the other boxes are respectively dd1, dd2, ...., dd7. I want to write a javascript function so that all the values in the textboxes dd1, dd2,...,dd7 are multiplied by N if I put N in the first textbox namely mm1. I can write the javascript function , but how to make its effect in all boxes simultaneously? I have tried the following code. But it can effect only one box depending on the value of $i. If we can create a loop for $i taking values 1 to 7, then perhaps the problem will be solved. Any clue please.

```
<?php $i=3?>
<input type="text" size="1" id="mm1" name="mm1" 
maxlength="2"  onfocus="this.select()"    
onkeyup="gft('dd<?php echo $i?>', 'mm1')"
>
```

Comment: Set a class on the other 7 textboxes, and loop through them in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use class to logically group elements...

```
$('.mult').each(function(i,v){
            var tt = parseFloat($(this).val());
            $(this).attr('data-val',$(this).val());
});
$('.myVal').on('keyup',function(e){
    var t = $(this).val();
    if(!t) t = 0;
    $('.mult').each(function(i,v){
            if(t>0){
                var tt = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-val')) * t;
                $(this).val(tt);
            }
    });
});
```

Find working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fa9y7zvb/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/w7syoyzm/) using only JavaScript (no jQuery):

HTML

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="multiply(this)"/>

<input type="number" value="1" class="multiply-this"/>
<input type="number" value="2" class="multiply-this"/>
<input type="number" value="3" class="multiply-this"/>
<input type="number" value="4" class="multiply-this"/>
<input type="number" value="5" class="multiply-this"/>
<input type="number" value="6" class="multiply-this"/>
<input type="number" value="7" class="multiply-this"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function multiply(first){
    var value = +first.value;
    var textboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("multiply-this");

    for(var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++){
        var textbox = textboxes[i];

        if(textbox.attributes.initialValue){
            textbox.value = textbox.attributes.initialValue.value;
        } else {
            textbox.setAttribute("initialValue", textbox.value);
        }

        textbox.value = +textbox.value * value;
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    var textboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("multiply-this");

    for(var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++){
        var textbox = textboxes[i];
        textbox.onkeyup = function(){
              this.setAttribute("initialValue", this.value); 
        }
    } 
}
```

I added functionality to remember what value the textboxes had at first. But you can still change it if you specifically change one of the 7 textboxes that gets multiplied.

**EDIT**

You can also add this if you want it to multiply after changing one of the values:

```
textbox.onblur = function(){
    multiply(document.getElementById("multiplyer"));
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/w7syoyzm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function gft(x){
    n = 5;
    c = x * n;
    textInputs[0].value = c;
    textInputs[1].value = c;
    textInputs[2].value = c;
}

var textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
//this eventlistener is made to listen for key movement on all text fields that are of type text
for(i=0;i<textInputs.length;i++){
    textInputs[i].addEventListener('keyup',function(){
        //gft will execute an equation whenever one of these fields change
        //also, it will change all the values inside the textfield simultaneously
        gft(this.value);
    },false);
}
```